# Kivy Gaussian blur

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

It is a Kivy user.
The other day I found something interesting in Github.
I definitely want to realize it, but I do not know why this happend even if I read the code.
It is the URL below. What kind of code can I use to apply this Gaussian blur?

[In GitHub](https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/284f1bd71da839ada1550c51ec2c91ef)

[Also found in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwIRVxVITEw)

Comment: What is the relationship between the github code and the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important parts are lines 60 and 61 in the linked code, plus line 42 to import the `MaskEffect`. You can do exactly the same thing in your own code, with an appropriate import and setting an EffectWidget's effect to MaskEffect.